# Making Menu coming From Left Corner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to make an **Menu Animation** just as shown below.

[image]

I need to have UIButtons inside the menu.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: Did you create your one view that show the menu ?

Comment: Actually i want to decide UIView or adding target UIViewController will get the thing done.

Comment: this menu is use in all controller that you have menu then its batter to use some library for this kind of menu

Comment: U can set your view animation in super class and inherit your super class and u can get your view animation all class

Comment: What if I will provide you a library for this. Will that works for you or do you need animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this animation you should set anchor point by default the anchor point position is (0.5,0.5), so can change the anchor point position:

All geometric manipulations to the view occur about the specified point. For example, applying a rotation transform to a layer with the default anchor point causes the layer to rotate around its center. Changing the anchor point to a different location would cause the layer to rotate around that new point.

```
self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001,0.001);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
          self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

   }];
```

Comment: Animation is working great. I need to have this view in all my view controllers.

Comment: Add the subview in all view controller. @Saranjith

Answer (score 1):

Please add the follow code on button click:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
                     myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5); }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                      animations:^{
                                          myView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                      }]; }];
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Super class SuperViewController.m
Add this method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Here u can set image also in navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonC = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Word" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(GeTVAlue)];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:buttonC];
}
-(void)GeTVAlue{

   UIView *paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-350, -350, 350, 350)];
    [paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:paintView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
                     paintView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.5, 2.5); }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                      animations:^{
                                          paintView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                      }]; }];
}
```

Then Inherit your Super class in your class

> **@interface TheerdViewController : SuperViewController**

If u have any question fill free ask me.
Thnak you